# Downloading Remote PLIST iOS - Returning Null

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, plist

Struggling with this one. Looking to download a read only plist for use inside my app...

However struggling to read the contents in a Dictionary... Code below, any pointers would be great..

```
-(void)loadProducts {


NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f1nmq1wa7gs96dp/Region1Products.plist"]];


for (NSDictionary* productDictionary in dict) {
    ProductItem* productItem = [[ProductItem alloc] init];

    productItem.picturesCount = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"PicturesCount"];
    productItem.maxPicturesCount = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"MaxPicturesCount"];
    productItem.size = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"Size"];
    productItem.previewImageName = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"ImageName"];
    productItem.sequence = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"Sequence"];
    productItem.productName = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
    productItem.type = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"ProductType"];
    productItem.prices = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"Prices"];
    productItem.shippingPrices = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"ShippingPrices"];
    productItem.description = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"Description"];
    productItem.popupMessage = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"PopupMessage"];
    productItem.popupDetailMessage = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"PopupDetailMessage"];
    productItem.incrementalPricing = [[productDictionary objectForKey:@"IncrementalPricing"] boolValue];
    if (YES == productItem.incrementalPricing) {
        productItem.incrementalPrices = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"IncrementalPrices"];
    }

    NSArray *previewItems = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"PreviewItems"];
    for (NSDictionary* previewItem in previewItems) {
        [productItem addProductPreviewItemFromDictionary:previewItem];
    }

    [self.productsList addObject:productItem];
}
```

Comment: please alloc your self.productsList Array :) this is an issue my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an NSDictionary from the url, but the top level object in that plist is an array. To solve this, you can change `dict` to an NSArray object. I used the following simplified code to test this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f1nmq1wa7gs96dp/Region1Products.plist"]];

for (NSDictionary* productDictionary in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@",productDictionary);
}
```

Comment: sort and simple answer very nice

Comment: Now i've got the age old issue that the plist is now being cached. Any ideas or techniques to prevent this happening? Maybe stringByAppendingFormat?